# objective-c json string to django-phonenumber-field "The phone number entered is not valid."

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, django

My iOS app needs to register new users with my website.  One of the required fields is a phone number so I am using a django-phonenumber-field, `PhoneNumberField`, on the server in the model.  My iOS code to send the POST request looks like this:

```
NSString *url = @"http://mywebsite.com/api/register";

NSString *post = @"name=test&email=test@test.com&phone_number=+15554443333&password=test";

NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[post length]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

NSURLConnection *con = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];

if(con) {
    NSLog(@"Connection Successful");
} else {
    NSLog(@"Connection could not be made");
}
```

Note: the "post" and "url" are usually passed in through a method call, but I just hard coded it in here for simplicity.

`PhoneNumberField` expects a number in international phone number format, which to the best of my knowledge is what I am using.  No matter what I put in for `phone_number` I always get back `{"phone_number":["The phone number entered is not valid."]}` as the response.  If I take out the phone_number from my model and use the same code (without `phone_number=+15554443333`) a new user gets registered on the server and everything works fine.

I have scavenged the internet high and low for my problem and can't find the solution anywhere.  Does anybody know what I am doing wrong?  Thanks.

The "name" in my model is a `CharField` and the "email" is a `EmailField`.

Comment: Seems like the problem is with how the server is reading the phone number. As the phone number error message is not being generated by your code, I would try debugging whatever you're doing on the server-side. Make sure that the object is being bound properly and whatnot.

Comment: I thought that too at first and did a bunch of debugging.  But after not finding anything and the fact that it works when I use the web interface for the django rest framework at that endpoint, I don't think the problem is with the server.

Comment: Don't make assumptions. Log exactly the input your app is submitting and try to reproduce. If said real input logs doesn't explain the issue, using live debugging tools like pdb on a development server and inspecting the input is a pretty bullet proof debugging tactic with unlimited tools at your disposal.

Comment: Also, include that information in your question. If you have it working in some situations but not others, that can be very valuable diagnostic information. Relevant details and specifics are your friends!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem.  I needed to URL encode the string, meaning the plus sign in

```
NSString *post =@"name=test&email=test@test.com&phone_number=+15554443333&password=test";
```

needed to be a %2B.  So the end string looks like

```
NSString *post =@"name=test&email=test@test.com&phone_number=%%2B15554443333&password=test";
```